Recepie example for changing application.properties (or yaml) for a Spring Boot 3 application
a newbie to write recepies. What I'm going to try to accomplish is to read an application.properties (or yamal) file and convert values and entries to different ones. I've been searching around but can't really find a good example that I can look at.
For example:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}
    username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}

change to something  like this:
spring:
  datasource:
    connectionString: ${spring.datasource.url}
    user: ${spring.datasource.username}
    pwd: ${spring.datasource.password}

So if anyone got something and can share it I'd appreciate it.
Thanks
Andy

Have you looked at the examples we have for other Spring properties?
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.SpringBootProperties_3_3
displayName: Migrate Spring Boot properties to 3.3
description: Migrate properties found in `application.properties` and `application.yml`.
tags:
  - spring
  - boot
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.java.spring.ChangeSpringPropertyKey:
      oldPropertyKey: spring.couchbase.env.ssl.key-store
      newPropertyKey: spring.couchbase.env.ssl.bundle

Taken from rewrite-spring/src/main/resources/META-INF/rewrite/spring-boot-33-properties.yml:
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/blob/18f671d02ed987610b0a7203ff89aaae8143af1c/src/main/resources/META-INF/rewrite/spring-boot-33-properties.yml#L19-L29

I think Tim's answer will handle your specific use case. There are additional recipes for adding and changing spring property values and these recipes will make changes to both properties and yaml formatted files.
The best way to get an idea of how these recipes work is to take a peek at the tests:
AddSpringPropertyTest
ChangeSpringPropertyTest
